# PhpMyAdmin keeps redirecting to login screen

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm having troubles logging in to PhpMyAdmin. 
When I press "login" after typing in my credentials, it just keeps going back to the login screen. I could login perfectly a few days ago. I don't know what I've done that's causing this.

I can login to mysql perfectly in the shell (mysql -D database -u user -ppassword). My sites are running as expected. What could this be?

Edit: logging in works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE
See reply #4 in this topic: https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/forums/forum/72909/topic/4479151

Thx.

Comment: you might get an answer in the forum superuser.com

Comment: I found myself in the same situation, and am using IE9 (corporate reasons). I tried changing the compatibility to IE7, IE9, IE9 compatibility. None worked. I downloaded Firefox, and it worked fine. Your workaround may be the answer; it might just be the current flavor of PhpMyAdmin doesn't play well with other browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After googling this issue for ages I finally figured out what it was in my case. The problem was that google chrome does a validity check against the timestamp of the cookie (or something like this). Simply make sure that the server with PMA installed on it has the correct date/time settings and isn't out of sync. This should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for this, was having this problem recently. Just as an aside question, the server I manage is in a different time zone, is there a way to counteract this?

Answer (score 3):

If all your configurations for phpMyAdmin are correct but the problem still persists, it could be due lack of disk space. If this is the case, you can use df -h to diagnose the space problem.

My scenario was that a cron was used to create mysqldump of a large database until the space ran out. After deleting the sql dumps, phpMyAdmin logged in as it should.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred when i switched to HTTPS, so just check that, could also be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with phpmyadmin works fine in Firefox, IE but not Chrome.
Clearing any cookies related to phpmyadmin (phpmyadmin or starting with "pma") solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur as well if the directories opcache, session and wsdlcache in /var/lib/php don't have sufficient permissions

We had to change the group ownership from apache to nginx

sudo -R chown root:nginx /var/lib/php

After changing the permissions we could login with phpmyadmin