# Why is phpmyadmin redirecting to login page after logging in?

Tags: phpmyadmin, debian, lamp

I browse to phpmy admin, enter my credentials click login, it then goes back to the login page with a token set in the url.

No errors (error reporting is on)
I can log in to the database over ssh
Time/date seems to be correct to within the minute on the server.
Tried multiple browsers and clearing cache.
config.inc.php is empty but secret_blowfish is set.

It worked after initially installing the lamp server (Debian wheezy on raspberry pi) but since the first power cycle of the server I have not been able to log in.

Please help!

Comment: try to clear your browser's cache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608550/phpmyadmin-keeps-redirecting-to-login-screen

Comment: try with https or clear your cache

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resolve, but i've ever experienced the same problem.
After redirected back to login page, you just need to refresh your browser to access your phpmyadmin.